# Query to retrieve multiple addresses for one client

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm sorry I can't find a concise way to describe what I need.
As a result I need only one record per client containing:

client_id, client_name, residential_address, delivery_address

Here's a simplified version of the table structure:

- Client (client_id, client_name)
- Address (address_id, client_id, address, address_type)
- AddressType (addresstype_id, addresstype_label)

I have a query that does this now BUT it's currently using hard-coded 'address_type' id's from the Address table. I'm currently not using the AddressType table in my query. **I need to rebuild the query so it no longer uses these hard-coded id's.**
That's because I use this query in different environments, and id's like these sometimes differ per environment because of low-code platform Outsystems. On Dev an id can be 1 while on Production it could be 2 for example.

Instead of for example 'AND ResidentialAddress.Address_type = 1' I need something like 'AND AddressType.addresstype_label = 'residential_address'

In total I must have spent a day on this and I just can't get it right. I either end up with multiple records per client, or only clients that both have a residential address AND a delivery address.

The current query with hard-coded id's looks like this:

```
SELECT 
   Client.client_id,
   client_name,
   ResidentialAddress.address AS ResidentialAddress,
   DeliveryAddress.address AS DeliveryAddress
From Client
LEFT JOIN Address ResidentialAddress ON Client.client_id = ResidentialAddress.client_id AND ResidentialAddress.address_type = 1
LEFT JOIN Address DeliveryAddress ON DeliveryAddress.client_id = Client.client_id AND DeliveryAddress.address_type = 2
```

If you want to try, this might be of help:

```
CREATE TABLE Client (
  client_ID int,
  client_name nvarchar(50)
);
CREATE TABLE Address (
  address_id int,
  client_id int,
  address nvarchar(50),
  address_type int
);
CREATE TABLE AddressType (
  addresstype_id int,
  addresstype_label nvarchar(20),
);
INSERT INTO Client
VALUES
  (1, 'John Smith'),
  (2, 'Pete Adams');
INSERT INTO Address
VALUES
  (1, 1, '23 Main Street', 1),
  (2, 2, '165 Park Street', 1),
  (3, 2, '6 Eighth Street', 2);
INSERT INTO AddressType
VALUES
  (1, 'residential_address'),
  (2, 'delivery_address');
```

This should be the result:

[image: Result]

Comment: Your SQL works fine, [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e1bf0b93e131b98f0705585a4b9dc3a7), what is the problem here?

Comment: I'm guessing the sample data provided is not complete enough to show the actual problem. Also, there appears to be no need for creating the AddressType table in this example since your query doesn't use it. I think I understand the problem, but need more information: if you are wanting to limit the number of rows returned, what is the criteria in which these records should be filtered? Also, please update your sample data so that we can actually see the problem. Per Larnu, the query you provided using the sample data you provided returns identical results to what you claim it "should" be.

Comment: I need the query to work without hard-coded id's (ResidentialAddress.address_type). That's because I use this query in different environments, and id's like these sometimes differ per environment because of low-code platform Outsystems.

Comment: Ok, but what values can be used to identify which row you need? For example, John Smith (while I only see one row for him) surely has some identifying value per row that tells you which address (and row) you want to pull for him.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand that question. Let's say the Client table contains 100,000 clients. The result should then be 100,000 rows. One row per client.
The Client table doesn't contain a foreign key that can be linked to the Address table, but the Address table contains a foreign key 'client_id'.
Let's say the Address table contains 101,000 row: 100,000 of these are residential addresses but 1,000 clients also have a delivery address. I hope this clears things up a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "subquery solution" also ensure that the client will show only once even if you add multiple delivery addresses for it.

```
SELECT 
   Client.client_id,
   client_name,
   ResidentialAddress = (
        select top 1 address 
        from 
            Address a 
            inner join AddressType at on at.addresstype_id=a.address_type 
        where a.client_id=Client.client_id and at.addresstype_label='residential_address'
    ),
    DeliveryAddress = (
        select top 1 address 
        from 
            Address a 
            inner join AddressType at on at.addresstype_id=a.address_type 
        where a.client_id=Client.client_id and at.addresstype_label='delivery_address'
    )
From Client
```